# HQL different behavior for null foreign key

Tags: nhibernate

Let's say I have two tables:
A has a foreign key into B
B has a column named "Name"

I need to get results for each row in A that return Name from B if the foreign key is not null, but null if the foreign key is null. I'm using NHibernate and would like to augment my HQL query with this behavior.

Thanks.

The tables could look like this:

```
A
------
| ID |
------
| 1  |
| 2  |
------

B
--------------------
| ID | A_id | Name |
--------------------
|  1 |  2   | Ben  |
--------------------

Results
---------------
| A_id | Name |
---------------
|   1  | NULL |
|   2  | Ben  |
---------------
```

Comment: In raw SQL, it would be something like: `select B.name from A left outer join B on A.id = B.A_id`

Comment: The problem is that I need a row in the results where there isn't a B that has an B.A_id that matches A.id

Comment: What? Please add an ASCii-art (or some other) picture to your question that shows the A table, the B table (with data) and a resulting table with the results you want. That will make it _much_ easier to understand what you are really after.

Comment: I edited the original question with what the tables might contain. I understand that this may not even be possible. I'm wondering if it is.

Comment: The query I gave you (with the left outer join) should give you something close to that. This will give you exactly that: `select A.ID as A_id, B.Name as Name from A left outer join B on A.ID = B.A_id`

Comment: Thanks for your help cdeszq, but I would like to avoid converting my HQL into pure SQL if I can. I wonder if there is a way to do this in HQL.

Comment: That's why I only posted the SQL as a comment and not an answer to your question, since you asked for HQL :) There definitely _is_ a way to do outer joins like that in HQL, but I don't know how off the top of my head. Take a read through the user guide for nHibernate (or Hibernate). I'm pretty sure they talk about outer joins in there in the HQL section: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.ID as A_id, b.Name as Name from A a left outer join a.Bs b
```

note: see the alias for a and the association of a to its Bs

Comment: I see, the problem I was running into was I was trying to do something more like: "select a.ID, a.B.Name from A a". That doesn't work if a.B is null.